# Windows CE barcode reader with MC55

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I have a Motorolla MC55 device and I'm looking forward to make a barcode reading application in Windows CE using VS2008. So what is the best SDK to use for barcode reading? and if a code sample is available would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use either the EMDK for C (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/emdk-for-c.html) or the EMDK for .NET (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/emdk-for-net.html).  The installer also copies sample applications to your user directory which contain examples of how to do barcode scanning

Answer (score 1):

You may want to contact Zebra Technologies Technical Support.
I think that the model number and the OS version number of the device you are using will tell you such information as which SDK is appropriate.

[CONTACT SUPPORT](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/about-zebra/contact-zebra/contact-tech-support.html)
EGYPT, JORDAN, KUWAIT, LEBANON, OMAN, QATAR, YEMEN  +420 533 336 123

[MC55X MOBILE COMPUTER SERIES](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/handheld/mc55-mobile-computer-series.html)

[ZEBRA ONECARE SUPPORT SERVICES](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/services/zebra-onecare-support-services.html)